# Evosuite TestGeneration ERROR - Not possible to access to clients. Clients' state: Terminated with exit status 1

Tags: junit

Kindly find the below error which i am getting in log file of evosuite:

[MASTER] 13:44:49.952 [main] ERROR TestGeneration - Not possible to access to clients. Clients' state: Terminated with exit status 1. Master registry port: 14510
[MASTER] 13:44:49.964 [main] ERROR SearchStatistics - No statistics has been saved because EvoSuite failed to generate any test case
[MASTER] 13:44:50.065 [main] ERROR TestGeneration - failed to write statistics data

Please Suggest what configuration changes  needs to make  in Evosuite to avoid this error.